# Exclude Posts in a Given Category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a Query that is pulling the newest post from 4 different custom post types that have a given category associated with them. I am trying to figure out how I can not show the newest post if it has the category of explore even though it also has the category of outdoor-recreation.

```
<?php
$myquery['tax_query'] = array(
'relation' => 'OR',

 array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'category__not_in' => array('explore'),
    'field' => 'slug',  
  ),
 array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'terms' => array('outdoor-recreation'),
    'field' => 'slug',  
 ),
 array(
    'taxonomy' => 'take_category',
    'terms' => array('outdoor-recreation'),
    'field' => 'slug',
),
 array(
    'taxonomy' => 'story_category',
    'terms' => array('outdoor-recreation'),
    'field' => 'slug',
  ),
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'news-category',
    'terms' => array('outdoor-recreation'),
    'field' => 'slug',
  ),

  );
  $myquery['showposts'] = 1;

  query_posts($myquery);

  while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
  $wp_query->the_post();

  ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to           <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
  <?php  
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()):  
the_post_thumbnail( 'feed-fixed' );  
endif;  ?></a>
 <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link      to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
 <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 20 ); ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to           <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">>>More</a>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
 ?>
```

Comment: In 99.99% of use-cases, you shouldn't be using `query_posts()` but a new instance of `WP_Query()` - See [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [Query Posts vs ...](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/7355)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the array contains a category not tested live but is valid PHP

```
    <?php
    $myquery['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',

      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'category__not_in' => array('explore'),
        'field' => 'slug',  
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array('outdoor-recreation'),
        'field' => 'slug',  
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'take_category',
        'terms' => array('outdoor-recreation'),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'story_category',
        'terms' => array('outdoor-recreation'),
        'field' => 'slug',
      ),
      array(
         'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
        'terms' => array('outdoor-recreation'),
        'field' => 'slug',
       ),

     );
     $myquery['showposts'] = 1;

     query_posts($myquery);

    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    $wp_query->the_post();

    // Get post id
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    // Check categories of post
    $categories = get_the_category($post_id);
    if (in_array("explore", $categories)) {
      // explore is in the array
    }
    else{
     // Not in array do something 
    }
    endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks I am not sure how to have it show what I need though. I basically what it to show what ever post is the newest that is not in the explore category but will display it the same way no mater what. My issue is that some times a post may have more then one category on it and some times it can be explorer I want it so that this one would not be shown but the next newest one would that has the term outdoor-recreation I have changed the code in my question to what I now have.

Comment: try using 'category__not_in' => array('2')   2 being the category number of explore